# how to exclude location in freebase search suggest?

Tags: google-api, freebase

how to exclude a continent and countries both from search suggestions in selecting locations so that i can use the remaining locations (i want to exclude continents and countries of asia EXCEPT India) ?

im using d below code:

```
$(function() {

$("#myinput")
  .suggest({
    "key": "abc",
  filter: '(all type:/location/)'
  })
 .bind("fb-select", function(e, data) {
   alert(data.name + ", " + data.id + " (" + data['n:type'].name + ")");
});

});
```

Comment: You probably want to delete (& invalidate) your API key.

Answer (score 1):

Freebase Search has a pretty powerful filter language that includes AND ("all"), OR ("any"), and NOT ("not") operators.  The documentation is split between the developer's web site and the mailing list, but you can find the basics here: https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-overview

Comment: filter: '(all type:/location/ not m/059g4)' is not working  ?